# Удаление класса у массива классов

Tags: javascript, классы

Добрый день.

Мне нужно, чтобы у каждого первого класса votest1, votest2, votest3 и т.д. удалялись классы voteds. Вот что получается для одного:

```
$(".votes1:first").removeClass('voteds')
```

Как сделать перечисление .votes1-N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так?

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    $(".votes" + i + ":first").removeClass('voteds')
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: n is not defined  - выдает такую ошибку.

Comment: >  Как сделать перечисление .votes1-N?

я исходил из того, что это n вам известно.
впрочем, вариант ниже кажется более красивым.

Comment: Спасибо, чего то я совсем затупил!) Все работает! Еще раз спасибо!))

Comment: @Илья Остапенко, попробуйте мой вариант, ни на что не претендую, но он более правильный в плане рациональности ;)

Comment: Согласен. Хотя бы потому, что в варианте @MasterAlex количество таких классов не фиксировано.

Comment: @iksuy, проверил, мой вариант не работает, он находит всего 1 элемент, поэтому удалю, чтобы не вводить народ в заблуждение

Comment: Да, тоже проверял его, не сработал, забыл написать об этом